# How to minimise repetition between conditions and return values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if there's a way to write this code in a more elegant fashion:

```
def default_price
  if project.hourly_rate.present?
    project.hourly_rate
  elsif project.person.hourly_rate.present?
    project.person.hourly_rate    
  elsif project.person.organisation.hourly_rate.present?
    project.person.organisation.hourly_rate
  else
    user.preference.hourly_rate
  end
end
```

There's a lot of repetition going on here between the conditions and the return values. Is there a better way to code this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def default_price
  [
    project.hourly_rate,
    project.person.hourly_rate,
    project.person.organisation.hourly_rate,
  ]
  .find(&:present?) ||
  user.preference.hourly_rate
end
```

or, to refactor a bit more:

```
def default_price
  [
    project,
    project.person,
    project.person.organisation,
  ]
  .find{|x| x.hourly_rate.present?}.hourly_rate ||
  user.preference.hourly_rate
end
```

Furthermore, if `user.preference.hourly_rate` is always `present?`, then you can further refactor:

```
def default_price
  [
    project,
    project.person,
    project.person.organisation,
    user.preference,
  ]
  .find{|x| x.hourly_rate.present?}.hourly_rate
end
```

Comment: OK, turns out that this code actually works better, so I ticked this one as the correct answer. With Mikhail's code I can easily run into a Nil object error.

Answer (score 3):

```
def default_price
    project.hourly_rate || project.person.hourly_rate || project.person.organisation.hourly_rate || user.preference.hourly_rate
end
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the OPs original code. This does not work the same when any of these are non-nil present objects.